# Perl substitute inserting junk when not asked as used in Ruby %x{}

Tags: ruby, perl

So I am running this one liner:

```
 perl -i -pe 's|[^\d\n]||g' country-ids.txt
```

To substitute text in a file that looks like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
files_to_change = ["db_owners.txt", "db_vessels.txt"]
files_to_change.each do |file|
    text = File.read(file)
,"1")
,"1")
,"2")
,"2")
,"3")
```

My goal is to strip each line of all non-digit characters while keeping the lines at their original places.

Instead of the result I want, I am getting this:

```
d
dd
d
d
<blank space>
```

Not sure what's going on. The reason I am preserving the new line is because the last time I ran it without the newline in the "find" character class all I got was one really, really long line of digits.

I am running this in a .rb script by using %x{command} if that makes any difference.

edit:

Here's the entire script. Still getting the same issue. Not sure why.

```
%x{cut -f 2 -d/ script-substitute-countries-with-id.rb > countries2.txt}
%x{cut -f 2 db_vessels.txt > countries.txt}
%x{cut -f 3 -d/ script-substitute-countries-with-id.rb > country-ids.txt}
%x{perl -i -pe 's:[^\d]::g' country-ids.txt}
%x{join countries2.txt country-ids.txt > countries2.txt.tmp}
%x{mv countries2.txt.tmp countries2.txt}
%x{cat countries.txt countries2.txt > countries.txt}
%x{uniq countries.txt > countries.txt.tmp}
%x{mv countries.txt.tmp countries.txt}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. I get "8  1 1 2 2 3" (with newlines). Looks like one of your backslashes are not there. Eg `[^d\n]` instead of what you wrote.

Comment: It works perfectly here.

Comment: If you are running Windows, replace the vertical bar | by backslash /

Comment: @texasbruce just curious: why?

Comment: @texasbruce / is not backslash. \ is backslash. On the other hand, it makes no difference what delimiter you use.

Comment: @sidyll Windows cannot distinguish if the vertical bar is a pipe or not, even they are quoted.

Comment: With the new edit: Geez, that's a lot of strange computation... why not just use perl all the way?

Comment: still getting used to Perl (and scripting in general) so...yeah. plus i have to do add stuff to it in ruby which i don't know how to say in Perl yet.

Comment: Why in the world are you doing perl and shell stuff that can be better done while staying in ruby?

Comment: @DGM — yup. ended up doing that at the end of the day after TLP told me to stick with Perl. sometimes you learn things the hard(dumb) way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby's `%x{}` operator applies double-quote like semantics, meaning that backslashes are special.  Change the perl code to: `'s|[^\\d\\n]||g'` (using 2 backslashes each place you had 1) and it should work.